# ¿Cómo hacer un intérprete en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas muy parecidas entre sí, las cuales tengo que validar los datos de una y otra, pero choco en que una de las tablas tiene un código antiguo y la otra tabla el código está actualizado, ¿cómo puedo hacer un interprete o una consulta en la cual pueda validar dichos datos?

tabla_antigua

| run | nombre | fecha. | local | codigo_antiguo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Juan. | 2021-11-02 | 654-22 | 07-002-6 |

tabla_nueva

| run | nombre | fecha. | local | codigo_antiguo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Juan. | 2021-11-02 | 654-22 | 07-022 |

tabla de códigos

| codigo_antiguo | codigo_nuevo | descripción |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07-002-6 | 07-022 | realizar movilidad |

Lo que necesito hacer es validar que los campos run, fecha_entrada_local y código sean concordantes en ambas tablas (tabla_antigua y tabla_nueva) pasando por la tabla de códigos en donde pueda realizar la conversión del código antiguo al código nuevo

Comment: Puedes relacionar la columna run entre las dos tablas? La diferencia entre el código antiguo y nuevo es siempre el guion y un número final?

Comment: Probaste algo? con un par de joins no deberias tener problema....

Comment: Te dejo la estructura para poder ir probando http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd277/4

Comment: @Vicent lo he probado asi, pero una persona puede tener mas de un codigo con mismo RUN, FECHA Y LOCAL, pero varian en el codigo, por ende tengo que validar si el codigo nuevo es equivalente al codigo antiguo

Comment: Escribe en la pregunta la consulta que has intentado.

Comment: Soy yo el único confundido por el uso del término *intérprete*? Está correcto utilizarlo en este contexto?

Comment: Cual de las dos tablas debes actualizar?

Comment: No hay columna `fecha_entrada_local` en las tablas objeto de consulta. @OscarSantander debe publicar con su pregunta el DDL de sus tres tablas `tabla_antigua` , `tabla_nueva` y la que llama `tabla de códigos`. Lo que a medias se entiende es que intenta cruzar `tabla_antigua` con `tabla_nueva` asumiendo una relacion 1-1 entre ellas a través de un grupo de columnas `run`, `fecha_entrada_local`, `código` de las cuales solo la primera (`run`) pertenece a las tablas las otras dos (`fecha_entrada_local`, `código`) de donde se obtienen? ¿Que quiere decir con "pasando por la tabla de códigos"?